Weblogic server configuration Source locator does not exist: oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.sourceLocator
I am encountering some problems installing WebLogic version 12.2.1.3.0 on Eclipse Oxygen. When I try to create a new local server instance in Eclipse, I cannot find the screen to specify the new local server. Additionally, when I attempt to start the server, I receive the following error message: "Source locator does not exist: oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.sourceLocator."
Can someone give me some advice on how to properly configure this?

installing weblogic from cmd promt
donload oxygen
create new server

